# Scala Generics vs Any

Tags: scala, generics, casting

In the code I'm working on I have a class called SuccessMessage with fields actorType (an enum) and payload. I am not sure what type to make payload.

If I make payload of type Any, I have to do a lot of gross looking instanceOf type casting to handle it later on in my code in more specific implementations.

If I use generics, and make payload of type T, my other classes have to also include the type T. For example, in a high level trait of mine called Commander, I have a method called handleSuccess that takes in a SuccessMessage, and it will have to be able to take in a success message of generic type T, forcing my commander to be of generic type T too.

I am not sure if I have to pick between these two lesser evils, or if there is a better way of doing it. I have to include some way of generifying payload, because Success Message requires a payload of different types.

EDIT:
There is an additional problem with generics. Commander has to be able to handle many different kinds of SuccessMessages, so if it takes a SuccessMessage[T] in handleSuccess, forcing Commander to be Commander[T], then Commander won't be able to handle success messages with different types (I think, not 100% sure).

EDIT 2:
Here is a short bit of commander:

```
trait Commander {
  def handleSuccess(message: SuccessMessage){
     //based on SuccessMessage.ActorType, do different stuff
  }

class SuccessMessage(val actorType: ActorType, val payload: Option[Any])
class SuccessMessage(val actorType: ActorType, val payload: Option[T])
```

EDIT 3: Here is a description of the workflow to better explain the problem.

- Commander send msg to Poller

  - Poller sends SuccessMessage(self, List[String]) to Commander
- Commander sends List[String] to Processor

  - Processor sends SuccessMessage(self, File) to Commander
- Commander sends File to Uploader

  - Uploader sends SuccessMessage(self, Boolean) to Commander
- and so on.

Therefore, we need SuccessMessage to take different types.

Comment: It'd be better if you showed us some code to help you with.  But, yes, retrofitting an existing class with generics can create a substantial design burden if the class is widely used throughout a project.... This is why it's best to have a well-developed domain object model before you start writing.

Comment: What, specifically, does `handleSuccess` do with the success message's payload value?

Comment: Are your "more specific implementations" subclasses that inherit from `SuccessMessage` or just classes that use it?

Comment: There is just a lot of code, so I didn't want to paste all of it. Essentially, I am using the akka actor system, so commander creates different actors, sends it a message to do something, and the actors will return SuccessMessages back to the commander. The payloads inside these SuccessMessages are of different types.

Comment: Made edits to add code samples.

Comment: @DanGetz it takes in a successMessage payload, and based on the actor type, will create another actor of a different type to send it a message (along with the payload)

Comment: @jstnchng so it does absolutely nothing that requires knowing what the type of the payload value is? Just resends it?

Comment: @DanGetz Yeah, that's correct. It doesn't care what type payload it is, only the crow (actors) that receive the payload care in order to do processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `T` has some type bounds that allow the compiler to assume certain things about its behavior, you will have to cast instances of T to some concrete type to use them for any explicit purpose. (Basically same issue as `Any`)

You might want to look at type-classes. Then you can define some kind of handler for each type, and match the incoming payload to the handler using an implicit type-class instance. (see https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum library)

EDIT: Example here -> https://gist.github.com/phaistos/51f0405a2f25812a5780
Basically you end up with a typeclass like:

```
@typeclass trait CommanderHandler[A] {
   def handle(payload: A): Unit
}
```

And then you make an instance for each type you want to use as a payload:

```
implicit val handlerInt: CommanderHandler[Int] = new CommanderHandler[Int] {
  def handle(payload: Int) { /* use the payload here */ }
}
```

And then you can make a function like this to handle them:

```
def consumePayload[T](t: T)(implicit h: CommanderHandler[T]) {
  h.handle(t)
}
```

The implicit you create for the given type must be available at the call site for `consumePayload`. Basically you're just wrapping the handler for each type in a nice little bundle.

This is the neatest pattern ive found for such things so far. Hope it helps. Make sure you read the docs for simulacrum if you use it, you will need to do some imports after creating the typeclass to make it work.

EDIT: As an alternative you could also look at polymorphic methods via shapeless: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values

Comment: "Unless T has some type bounds that allow the compiler to assume certain things about its behavior, you will have to cast" is that meant as a general statement, or specific for the question?

Comment: For the first case I would like to add that `T` without type bounds is still better then `Any` because it stores the type information and helps to avoid casts e.g. in collections or model objects.

Comment: You can't call a method or access a field on a T, so the generic methods body can't do anything to it without a cast or bound.

Comment: Or I suppose you could use reflection with a runtime penalty. Regardless the typeclass pattern allows you to impose runtime behavior on any type without modifying those types, and without reflection.

Comment: What I mean is to clarify that `T` without type bounds is not equivalent to `Any` for all cases. If you have e.g. a `List[Int]`, you can retrieve elements from the list without having to cast to `Int`. If it was a list of Any, you would have to cast.

Comment: The OP's `Commander` class intentionally doesn't have `T` -- it accepts `SuccessMessage`s of various types.If he only handled one type of `SuccessMessage` and he specialized his `Commander` to some type `T`, then yes he would not need to cast -- but that has nothing to do with his example.

Comment: Here is a gist that demonstrates the problem at hand, and how to solve it with a typeclass -> https://gist.github.com/phaistos/51f0405a2f25812a5780

Comment: Which is why I first asked if the statement was meant to be general or specific for this question. If it's specific for the question then it makes sense. I was addressing the case that it is a general statement.

Comment: Generally. Erasure guarantees that inside a generic method's implementation that an unbound `T` has no more context than an `Any`. There is no code you can write inside a generic method that couldn't be rewritten with `Object` directly replacing the `T`. Because that's what actually happens.

Comment: That's correct but with "general" I mean inside the generic method/class as well as outside. Outside `T` does make a difference. Your initial statement sounded like `T` can be replaced with Any in all possible contexts.

Comment: Not only can you (with a few additional casts), but before Java got generics in 1.5 you had to.

Comment: All I did is only clarifying that the use of `T` makes a difference compared to `Any`, in the general context. Of course it's possible to use `Any` instead but then as you say you have to cast. Why are we interchanging so many messages about it? Not seeing how this almost obvious clarification leads to this long conversation/discussion.